# Difference between rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to generate a new table in mysql which contains the difference between every two rows..
For example, if I have this table:

table1:

```
ID     VALUE

1      16748 
1      19628
1      23245
1      23322
1      33399
2      15367
2      17839
2      34578
2      53421
3      14229
3      19533
........
```

I would like to get the difference between 2 consecutive values (row[x+1]-row[x]), for all values per ID

So my result would be:

```
ID      DIFF

1       2880
1       3617
1       77
1       10077
2       2472
2       16739
2       18843
3       5304
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: well, how can I do that?

Comment: You're looking for a single QUERY that will do this or some PHP code?

Comment: i'm interested in the query to get the result as shown above

Comment: do you have a date field too? how do identify which of the records were inserted first?

Comment: The main issue here is there is no such thing as "consecutive rows" in a table. A table is an *unordered set* of rows. If you want those rows to be ordered, you will have to provide an *explicit* mean of ordering them. And in your example, there is *no* column that could be used to *deterministically* order your rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
SELECT
    MIN(T2.VALUE- T1.VALUE) AS Dif
FROM
    Table T1 INNER JOIN Table T2 on T1.VALUE< T2.VALUE
ORDER BY
    T1.VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly that by joining the table with itself.

```
SELECT (first.value - second.value) AS differ FROM `table` AS first JOIN `table` AS second WHERE first.id + 1 = second.id
```